# Skin to verticies

Tags: 3d-printing, solidify-modifier

I am a novice to blender and 3D printing. Recently I discovered how to use the solidify modifier and can already see how versatile and useful it will be. My issue is that when I convert the object to an STL file (for 3D printing purposes), it treats the skin as another surface. This leaves me with a hollow object when I try to slice the file for 3D printing in Cura. I want a solid object that resembles the skin I made from the solidify modifier. How can I accomplish this?
I have tried finding ways to generate vertices from a skin thinking if I did that I could delete the original vertices (they are already saved as part of a vertex group and could be easily removed).
I have also searched for ways to thicken an object by actually moving vertices but haven't found any easy solution there either. Plus, if I can figure this out, it means I can mess with skins in my projects in the future. That would be pretty sweet!
Any thoughts?

To see what I am working on for visualization go to: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:165320

I want to thicken the strands to make it more durable for my toddler daughter. Also I need to shrink the bracket so it fits on her wrist without compromising the durability (strands need to be thick enough). So far I have added the solidify modifier and shrunk it so the object skin is the perfect size for her little hand to fit through. I'm happy with how it looks in blender and how the outside of it appears in Cura. I just need it to not be hollow.
I also would just like to see how best to approach similar situations for future reference.
Thank you in advance for any advice given!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of a solidify modifier is to create two layers of mesh, an inside and an outside.  For what you're showing, using it to "thicken" a mesh, you can just use a displace modifier instead.  When used without a specified texture, on default settings, a displace modifier simply moves vertices along their normals.  Set the midlevel to 0 and the strength to the same thickness you used for your solidify modifier:

[image]

In certain circumstances, it can be useful to create a solidify modifier, then destroy the mesh created by it.  (Not in your case, not here, but it can be useful if you want to use that solidified mesh with other modifiers that affect the original mesh.)  That's also possible.  First, create a vertex group on your mesh, then you set that vertex group as an output vertex group for the shell on the solidify modifier.  Afterwards, you can delete those vertices by referencing that vertex group in a mask modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!